# Call two different activites on a single layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show two different activites of a single application into a single layout..

e.g. I have divided my screen into two parts...Now on first part..It is a listview and on the second view , it is a content...

Now whenever user click on listview item then on the same layout, on the content section, we call different activity and show the content from that activity..

suppose there are 4 list in a listview and whever user click on the list item then it call another acvity and that activity content is to be shown on the content section of the same layout.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) but you cannot have two `Activity`'s shown at the same time or contained within a single layout.

Comment: But Fragments are available in 3.0 version ...and currently am working on 2.3 version

Comment: wrong there's http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html you should read about it

Answer (score 0):

Use `<include>` and other tags provided in the following links:

[Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

[Layout Tricks: Using ViewStubs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html)

[Layout Tricks: Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

[Layout Tricks: Merging Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all forget to use two activity. It is not the right way. I would suggest to use Fragment or you can display list in one activity and on click of list item open the other activity to display detail content of it(The easier and right one).

Answer (score -2):

You should start your activity for result and get content data from intent onActivityResultMethod.

```
startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
```

and on Receiving side:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Wrong answer Sam. I think you didnt understand question properly.

Comment: @sam: Please check your answer.

Comment: Sorry,I miss understand question.This will be valid for two different layouts not for one layout.